# create and organise file with R

Tags: r, file, directory

I have several images in one folder and I would like to automatically create folders and put my images into those one according to the images file name.
So, the name of the file are SMARTX_T001_L001_2021.07.19 , with T being Tube number (42 in total), L being depth (75 in total), and the last number is the date of the session (2 for now, but it will increase).
I would like to create for each tube number a file and within each tube file another file for the session dates, like C:\Users\Tube1\Session_2021.07.19\SMARTX_T001_L001_2021.07.19
In total, it would result in 42 main files with each 2 session files, each including 75 images.
Thanks for your hints!

Comment: Have you seen my answer? Does that help your case?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with this solution to generate the paths in one Table

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(filename="SMARTX_T001_L001_2021.07.19") %>% 
  tidyr::extract(filename, regex="SMARTX_T(\\d+)_L001_([\\d\\.]+)", into=c("Tube", "Session"), remove = F) %>% 
  mutate(path=file.path("C:/Users/", paste0("Tube", Tube), paste0("Session", Session), filename))
```

Afterwards you can easily move everything by looping over the table.

PS: see the regex explained here: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hztPhy/1)